# WCF - IMetadataExchange could not be found in the list of contracts implemented by the service

Tags: wcf

I'v been attempting to configure my WCF service to expose both SOAP and Json endpoints. However in doing so I seem to have broken my MEX endpoint with the error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The contract name 'IMetadataExchange' could not be found in the list of contracts implemented by the service TestService.  Add a ServiceMetadataBehavior to the configuration file or to the ServiceHost directly to enable support for this contract.

```
  <configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true"/>
  </system.web>
  <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's 
  app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name ="soapBinding">
          <security mode="None"/>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="webBinding"/>
      </webHttpBinding>
      <mexHttpBinding>
        <binding name="mexBinding"/>
      </mexHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="poxBehavior">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="jsonBehavior">
          <enableWebScript  />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="defaultBehavior">
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service name="TVD_WCF_Services.TestService" behaviorConfiguration="defaultBehavior">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <!-- note, choose an available port-->
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/TVD_WCF_Services/TestService/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint address="soap" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="soapBinding" contract="TVD_WCF_Services.ITestService" />
        <endpoint address="pox" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webBinding" behaviorConfiguration="poxBehavior" contract="TVD_WCF_Services.ITestService" />
        <endpoint address="json" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webBinding" behaviorConfiguration="jsonBehavior" contract="TVD_WCF_Services.ITestService" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="mexBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>

  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

I'm sure there is something wrong with the config but for the life of me I cannot work out what it is. Note that I have not changed anything other than the App.config so far so I'm sure the problem lies within.

I've looked at the various other questions related to this on the site but to no avail.

Any WCF gurus out there that can help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an issue with having SOAP, Xml and Json endpoints defined together on a single service in .NET 4.0 framework.

Just remove either the Xml or Json endpoint and it should work without any problem. If you want both to work you can set it to .NET 3.5 where it would work without any problem.

I have looked at the source code for both the framework and there is a difference which is causing this issue.

Please find the **[link](https://connect.microsoft.com/wcf/feedback/details/711802/hosting-multiple-endpoints-soap-xml-and-json-causes-an-exception-when-accessing-the-service)** to the Microsoft connect where I have raised this as a bug. Please do vote so that MS takes it and fixes the issue in a later release.

Comment: Thanks, but I've removed all but the MEX endpoint but still get the same error

Comment: You need to have atleast one endpoint defined along with mex endpoint.

Comment: Not sure why but removing poxBehaviour and defaultBehaviour and the pox endpoint did it. Cheers.

Comment: Sadly, the Microsoft link is now broken.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding"
             bindingConfiguration="mexBinding" 
             contract="System.ServiceModel.Description.IMetadataExchange" />
```

I believe the contract attribute needs the fully qualified type name.

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't do it :(

Comment: I'm getting the same issue, I've tried both of the solutions listed, and neither worked, including the fully qualified name to the MetadataExchange Interface.

Comment: All of this WCF seems highly inconsistent in behavior. If you fully qualify the IMetadataExchange the exception message changes to "The contract name .... could not be found in the list of contracts of the service implementation". If you just use IMetadataExchange then it says it couldn't find IMetadataExchange either.

Answer (score 0):

Sixto

Make sure that the project that you have the app.config/web.config in has a reference to System.ServiceModel

regards 
GregJF

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem.
Finally, I found that I didn't ref `System.ServiceModel` in main project.
Please check the reference.